# Angular mat-select and mat-option not showing

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

My mat-option content wasn't showed in ui , and I did import MatSelectModule , MatOptionModule and MatFormFieldModule into Module.ts file. Does anyone had this issue before ?
This is an Angular doc's example: https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview
html file :

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label i18n="Select label">Select an option</mat-label>
  <mat-select>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value" > {{food.value}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

ts file :

```
interface Food {
  value: string;
  viewValue: string;
}

Component ...


  foods: Food[] = [
    {value: 'steak-0', viewValue: 'Steak'},
    {value: 'pizza-1', viewValue: 'Pizza'},
    {value: 'tacos-2', viewValue: 'Tacos'}
  ];
  constructor(){...}
```

[This is UI result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/neBTy.png)

Comment: Hi nicole, welcome to StackOverflow! Your screenshot doesn't seem to match the code you've provided for your component - could you please include a [mcve] of the problem you're facing? Additionally, did you ensure that you've added [theming](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming) to your app?

Comment: It looks like the snippets you provided were (1) of an Angular help example and (2) a bit of your code that's not relevant to your question.  Please include some of your code that's relevant to your question; this will help people assist you.

Comment: @nicole did you get solution to this, I am aslo facig same issuse

Comment: I'm facing same issue, mat-select not showing options, applied different solutions, nothing worked out.